# Reply to desk rejection?

Tags: journals, etiquette

I recently got a desk rejection for a paper submitted to a journal. It was about as generic as a desk rejection form response can get: an "outside the scope of this journal" response; no personalized feedback at all. I was wondering whether to send a brief, polite thank-you.

I have searched around the Internet, and it seems opinions are kind of split with a slim majority saying if it's a desk rejection, don't respond at all. Some who advocate for that are quite adamant, saying it would be an inbox nightmare for editors if every desk rejectee sent a response, no matter how brief. But there were a few on the other side, saying it's always a good idea to send a (very brief) thank-you.

The boiler-plate response I got said that the journal hoped this would not discourage me from making future submissions. I was wondering if there have been any published surveys of journal editorial staff querying their reactions to replies to desk rejections. Does it affect their decision-making in future submissions from the same author?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I think all you will get is opinions.

Comment: There is no upside.  The editor will not be your friend.

Answer (score 14):

It does not matter.  There is no etiquette requirement that you should do so, but neither would it be unduly rude to send a note.

If the editor sees an e-mail from you, coming on the heels of a desk rejection, they will probably be pleasantly surprised when they start reading the e-mail and find that it is a short, polite note of thanks for their work—rather than the bitter complaint e-mail they were expecting.  This might give the editor a quick smile, but you have also used up a certain amount of their time, and the smile will almost certainly be quickly forgotten as they move on with their workload.

Answer (score 7):

This isn't necessary. Once a paper is desk rejected it's out of the journal's hands and likely their minds as well, since they have nothing more to do and are not expecting to have anything more to do.

Such a reply does say you have received the decision, but you kind of must have received the decision, since after all you submitted the paper using that email address. Not to say you can't send such a reply, it's just not necessary. The journal editor is likely to delete such a reply with no response.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I am leaning towards a very brief thank you note in response.